# Convert LaTeX to ePub

Tags: latex, converters, epub

**Update 2012-02-11 : Since my question is quite old but very popular, I'd propose to reopen it. I'd like to know, if more options are available a year later.**

I'd like to convert some university papers from LaTeX into ePub format - without using PDF as intermediate format. You know, PDF is page-oriented, while ePub is more flow-oriented.

While I found several hints, I failed to find a good 'standard' solution.

Could someone please propose the ideal way? One which keeps mathematical formulas render beautiful?

[Using TeXShop on Mac OS X]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm assuming you have an iPad. How about making LaTeX to compile to a pdf of a size optimized for iPad?

Comment: Now, I own an iPad. In fact, the iPad renders PDFs nicely. At the time I posted the question, I owned a Kindle - and Amazons PDF -> Kindle web service corrupted the PDF totally. Not even a single formula appear as it should. Thus, I asked.

Comment: This question has received more complete answers at tex.sx: [Use LaTeX to produce Epub](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) supports conversion from Latex to e-Pub.  The chances are high that it doesn't handle *your* Latex documents completely, but it should help with the conversion process.

Pandoc has converted Tex formulae to Mathml; I don't know how good that conversion is since I haven't used it.

Comment: I've recently used Pandoc to create an ePub file from LaTeX sources (including lstlisting embedded source code), and the result is really, really good.

Answer (score 11):

You could generate the TeX output in HTML, and then use the [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com) tools to convert. Basically ePub is about being a container for HTML docs (just like CHM fwiw). As an alternative, consider [BookGlutton](https://www.bookglutton.com/api/convert.html) and/or LyX

Comment: Which is the best HTML publishing tool for LaTeX?

Comment: Plastex is very goood and highly customizable, open source in Python